# Rails - Getting data from a table for each iteration of a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, each

Sorry for this newbie question but I cannot figure how I can do this..

I have the following City table

```
# Table name: cities
#
#  id          :integer
#  name        :string(255)
#  country     :string(255)
```

(note: I am not using a separate Country table as I use Geokit-rails and think it is simpler to store all Google queries in the same table. However It would be easier to have separate tables to render what I want through a belong_to/has_many association)

In my city/index view I want to loop all the cities for each countries in order to render something like:

```
United States
  New York
  San Francisco
  Los Angeles
United Kingdom
  London
Spain
  Madrid
...
```

By now, What I can get is what it provided by scaffolding

## Model

```
def index
  @cities = City.all
end
```

## View

```
<table>
  <% for city in @cities %>
  <tr>
    <th><%= city.country %></th>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><%= city.name %></td>
  </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Rendering:

```
United States
  Los Angeles
United States
  New York
...
```

I didn't find any resource about this. I would be pleased if someone could help me (I don't know with which I have to start: find_by_ /params /each or collection?)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to create a `Country` table with `id` and `name` and in your `City` model just keep a `country_id` to the country, instead of a string

so

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
end
```

then you can call `Country.includes(:cities)` and iterate over them like this in your view:

```
<% for country in countries %>
  <%= country.name %>
  <% for city in country.cities %>
    <%= city.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you still want to use your way, you could do something like

```
@cities = City.order("country asc")
@countries = @cities.map(&:country).uniq!

<% for country in @countries %>
  <%= country.name %>
  <% for city in @cities %>
    <%= city.name if city.country == country %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with the [`group_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method:

```
@cities.group_by(&:country).each do |country, cities|
  puts country.name
  cities.each do |city|
    puts "-> #{city.name}"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
United States
-> New York
-> San Francisco
-> Los Angeles
United Kingdom
-> London
Spain
-> Madrid
-> Barcelona
```

Of course, you'll probably be doing this in an erb template, but the idea is the same:

```
<ul>
    <% @cities.group_by(&:country).each do |country, cities| %>
        <li><%= country.name %></li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <% cities.each do |city| %>
                    <li><%= city.name %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Output:

- United States

  - New York
  - San Francisco
  - Los Angeles
- United Kingdon

  - London
- Spain

  - Madrid
  - Barcelona

Answer (score 0):

The official [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) are an excellent place to start ;)